# Add custom headers to 'request'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, httprequest

I am proxying my API via following setup in my express config

```
  // Proxy api calls
  app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    let url = config.API_HOST + req.url
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
  })
```

`config.API_HOST` in here resolves to my API URL and `req.url` is some endpoint i.e. `/users` I tried following documentation on npm for [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers) and set up my headers like so

```
  // Proxy api calls
  app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    let options = {
      url: config.API_HOST + req.url,
      options: { 'mycustomheader': 'test' }
    }
    req.pipe(request(options)).pipe(res)
  })
```

But I am not able to see my custom headers in Chrome dev tools under Network.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Was able to achieve it this way

```
  app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    let url = config.API_HOST + req.ur
    req.headers['someHeader'] = 'someValue'
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
  })
```

Comment: So when you do a get request to /api, it will be sent a 'someHeader' header with 'someValue' value?

Comment: This worked for me too. I tried setting the header with res.setHeader but it didnt' work. req['token] = "some_token" worked. I'm wondering if its safe though..

Comment: Just be careful, I just noticed that the headers that are already included with the received requests can be read via `req.get("abc)` and will return `undefined` for headers that are added via `req.headers.abc = 'xyz'`. On the other hand, `const x = req.headers.abc` will return the value of headers created via `req.headers.abc = 'xyz'` while `undefined` for headers included in the actual request received.

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: best answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451526/1308590