# Express, how to set custom request headers on all routes for all requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have this node API wrapper service, where I need to set REQUEST custom headers on all routes / endpoints at once instead of doing that on each request. I have tried the following in `app.js` but receive a not function error: `req.set is not a function`.

```js
const customHeadersAppLevel = function (req, res, next) {
  req.set("User-Agent", "zendx/sop API");
  next();
};
app.all("*", customHeadersAppLevel);
```

Is there anyway we can do this on the app level or should I just go ahead with setting custom request headers on individual routes/requests, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `app = express()` and we are at the top of the server's root file, you could set those headers for all your request like this:

```
const customHeadersAppLevel = function (req, res, next) {
  req.headers['User-Agent'] = 'zendx/sop API'
  next();
};

app.use(customHeadersAppLevel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no `set` function in `Request`. Use `headers` property to set the request header.

```js
 const customHeadersAppLevel = function (req, res, next) {
    req.headers['User-Agent'] = 'zendx/sop API';
    next();
 };
 app.all('*', customHeadersAppLevel);
```

You can also use Application-level middleware. Something [like this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application),

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.headers['User-Agent'] = 'zendx/sop API';
  next()
})

// Other Route comes here
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is how can I see I am setting the right headers. When I hit the endpoint in browser or postMan, I either get the browser or postman set as a user agent instead